# Retrieve attributes which do not have NULL or specific value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'school_record_upto_class5', which looks like below:

```
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+
| stu_id | stu_name | stu_add | no_of_class | stu_year1 | stu_percentage1 | stu_totalnum1 | stu_year2 | stu_percentage2 | stu_totalnum2 | stu_year3 | stu_percentage3 | stu_totalnum3 | stu_year4 | stu_percentage4 | stu_totalnum4 | stu_year5 | stu_percentage5 | stu_totalnum5 |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+
| 101    | abc      | India   | 2           | class1    | 78.13           | 625           | class2    | 72.00           | 360           |           |                 |               |           |                 |               |           |                 |               |
| 202    | abc1     | Nepal   | 3           | class1    | 82.00           | 656           | class2    | 84.17           | 673           | class3    | 73.17           | 80.06         |           |                 |               |           |                 |               |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+
```

here I want to retrieve the attributes with some values. So I have tried the below query:

```
select stu_id,stu_name,stu_add,
    -> stu_year1,stu_percentage1,stu_totalnum1,
    -> stu_year2,stu_percentage2,stu_totalnum2,
    -> stu_year3,stu_percentage3,stu_totalnum3,
    -> stu_year4,stu_percentage4,stu_totalnum4,
    -> stu_year5,stu_percentage5,stu_totalnum5
    ->  from sch_rec where stu_id='101' and
    -> ((stu_year1!='' and stu_percentage1!='' and stu_totalnum1!='') ||
    -> (stu_year2!='' and stu_percentage2!='' and stu_totalnum2!='') ||
    -> (stu_year3!='' and stu_percentage3!='' and stu_totalnum3!='') ||
    -> (stu_year4!='' and stu_percentage4!='' and stu_totalnum4!='') ||
    -> (stu_year5!='' and stu_percentage5!='' and stu_totalnum5!=''));
```

but it retrieves the whole table. and the below query retrieves empty set:

```
select stu_id,stu_name,stu_add,
    -> stu_year1,stu_percentage1,stu_totalnum1,
    -> stu_year2,stu_percentage2,stu_totalnum2,
    -> stu_year3,stu_percentage3,stu_totalnum3,
    -> stu_year4,stu_percentage4,stu_totalnum4,
    -> stu_year5,stu_percentage5,stu_totalnum5
    ->  from sch_rec where stu_id='101' and
    -> ((stu_year1!='' and stu_percentage1!='' and stu_totalnum1!='') and
    -> (stu_year2!='' and stu_percentage2!='' and stu_totalnum2!='') and
    -> (stu_year3!='' and stu_percentage3!='' and stu_totalnum3!='') and
    -> (stu_year4!='' and stu_percentage4!='' and stu_totalnum4!='') and
    -> (stu_year5!='' and stu_percentage5!='' and stu_totalnum5!=''));
```

I want to build a select query which will retrieve the below structure:

```
+--------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+
| stu_id | stu_name | stu_add | stu_year1 | stu_percentage1 | stu_totalnum1 | stu_year2 | stu_percentage2 | stu_totalnum2 |
+--------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+
| 101    | abc      | India   | class1    | 78.13           | 625           | class2    | 72.00           | 360           |
+--------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+
```

'no_of_class' attribute might also help in this case.

Below I'm attaching my sql queries to build this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sch_rec` (stu_id varchar(20),stu_name varchar(20),stu_add varchar(20),no_of_class varchar(20),stu_year1 varchar(20),stu_percentage1 varchar(20),stu_totalnum1 varchar(20),stu_year2 varchar(20),stu_percentage2 varchar(20),stu_totalnum2 varchar(20),stu_year3 varchar(20),stu_percentage3 varchar(20),stu_totalnum3 varchar(20),stu_year4 varchar(20),stu_percentage4 varchar(20),stu_totalnum4 varchar(20),stu_year5 varchar(20),stu_percentage5 varchar(20),stu_totalnum5 varchar(20)); 
INSERT INTO `sch_rec` VALUES ('101','abc','India','2','class1','78.13','625','class2','72.00','360','','','','','','','','',''),('202','abc1','Nepal','3','class1','82.00','656','class2','84.17','673','class3','73.17','80.06','','','','','','');
```

Comment: Your first query will not retrieve the whole table. If it does for you, you probably missed or misplaced some brackets. Make sure you post the actual query (or just try this one). Also, as a general warning, your table design isn't how you usually should do it (and may fail a homework task). Feel free to ask about how/why/help, but to store a student with n years of classes, you would create e.g. a table `student(id, name, add)` (2 rows) and a 2nd table `classes(studentid, year, class, percentage, totalnum)` (5 rows: (101, 1, ...), (101, 2, ...), (202, 1, ...), (202, 2, ...), (202, 3, ...)).

Comment: I'm afraid if I was going there, I wouldn't start from here. Consider normalising your schema, in the manner suggested by Solarflare

Comment: thank you so much for comments. But I have just posted a sample question of my application. Actually it's a small part and sample of a big application. I have tried to solve these kind of problems using BCNF. But the company's database structure doesn't allow me to do so. @Strawberry

Comment: I have tried the first query, but it picks the whole table and I have posted the actual query. and I just copy paste it from MySQL console. please suggest me some other possible way or some solution. thank you in advance. i stacked here from last 2 days.@Solarflare

Comment: I just think you're heading down a dark and miserable path, without radically restructuring your data.

Comment: @AmitKKushwaha Sorry, I think I misread your problem. You want to remove columns that contain null? (I thought you didn't want to have get all rows). You can't do this in a query (the output structure is decided before the query runs). If you want to show less columns, hide them in your application (which might solve your actual task, maybe you just try to solve it at the wrong place). You *could* use 2 queries: first get the number, then send different queries based on that number. But in general, there is something troubling here (both with the goal and the data model), so keep that in mind.